# Sapreste dirmi se "girarsi i pollici" è una espressione comunemente usata?

Tags: grammar, idioms

Sì, ho sentito questa espressione alcune volte e ho imparato a ripeterla, ma ho l'impressione che non tutti la comprendano.

Sapreste dirmi se si tratta di un localismo o se, magari, chi non la comprende dovrebbe invece impararla in quanto comunemente in uso?

Esempio:

> Giuletta, con tutte queste cose da fare stai lì a girarti i pollici.

Inoltre, non sono sicuro che l'espressione maggiormente in uso sia "girarsi i pollici" piuttosto che "rigirarsi i pollici". Sicché chiedo lumi anche su questo.

Comment: Kyriakos, prima non l'ho notato ma la parola "Sì" ha l'accento, senza accento è una particella riflessiva. :D

Answer (score 9):

L'espressione "girare i pollici" è comunemente usata per dire che qualcuno perde tempo senza fare niente. È capita dalla maggior parte delle persone, visto che non è un'espressione locale.
Forse dipende più dall'età della persona che dalla provenienza geografica; persone giovani potrebbero non capirla.

Ho sempre sentito dire "girarsi i pollici", non "rigirarsi i pollici".

Comment: *persone giovani potrebbero non capirla*. Ecco, adesso mi sento vecchio.

Answer (score 5):

Sicuramente è italiano, magari non è più tanto usata come un tempo come sinonimo di far niente, grattarsi la pancia, stare con le mani in mano, oziare.

Come tutte le parole e i modi di dire, anche girarsi i pollici subisce il mutare dei tempi e oggi è più facile sentirsi dire che "non si sta facendo un cavolo" o "si sta perdendo tempo".

Comment: Aggiungerei *è inutile  star qui a guardarsi l'ombelico* al tuo elenco... solo perché l'ho sempre trovata un'espressione simpatica.